# Add Icon to Tab (QTabWidget)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget, qicon

I'm working with a `QTabWidget` with three `Tabs`. 
One of the tab is about Information/Help. So I want to use a picture of a Question Mark (**.png**) instead of the Text "help".

Is this Possible? I'm working with *Python*/*PyQt* and I can only find solutions for *C++*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> int QTabWidget::addTab(QWidget *page, const QIcon &icon, const QString &label)
>
> Adds a tab with the given page, icon, and label to the tab widget, and returns the index of the tab in the tab bar. Ownership of page is passed on to the QTabWidget.

---

> void QTabWidget::setTabIcon(int index, const QIcon &icon)
>
> Sets the icon for the tab at position index.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.qtabwidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self) 
        
        widget  = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit("QPlainTextEdit 1")
        label   = 'Tab &1'
        widget2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit("QPlainTextEdit 2")
        
        tab_index1 = self.qtabwidget.addTab(widget, label)
        
        tab_index2 = self.qtabwidget.addTab(widget2, 'Tab &2')
        self.qtabwidget.setTabIcon(tab_index2, QtGui.QIcon('im.png'))                # <---  
        self.qtabwidget.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32)) 
        
        self.qtabwidget.addTab(
                QtWidgets.QLabel("QLabel Tab &3", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter), 
                QtGui.QIcon('Ok.png'),                                               # < ---
                'Tab &3')
        
        self.qtabwidget.addTab(None, "No Widget")
        
        self.qtabwidget.setTabsClosable(True)  
        self.qtabwidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.qtabwidget_tabcloserequested)
        self.qtabwidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular)
        self.qtabwidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.East)  
        self.qtabwidget.setTabEnabled(0, False)         # disable tab
        self.qtabwidget.setTabEnabled(1, True)          # enable tab
        self.qtabwidget.currentChanged.connect(self.qtabwidget_currentchanged)
       
        self.setCentralWidget(self.qtabwidget)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def qtabwidget_tabcloserequested(self, index):
        # gets the widget
        widget = self.qtabwidget.widget(index)
        # if the widget exists
        if widget:
            widget.deleteLater()
        # removes the tab of the QTabWidget
        self.qtabwidget.removeTab(index)
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def qtabwidget_currentchanged(self, index):
        print(f"\n New index of current page: {index}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle('QTabWidget')
    window.resize(400, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image]